# Powershell to get the required substring from a string

Tags: powershell

I have a string which looks something like this:

```
"Comments : @{id=15161772,we are happy with the service,likes=&÷€$:#,hsbdinsjsonsjbdjdjid}"
```

I would like to get the part "We are happy with the service".

I have tried something like:

```
$string ="Comments : @{id=15161772,we are happy with the service,likes=&÷€$:#,hsbdinsjsonsjbdjdjid}"
$string.split(",") | foreach {if(($_ -Notlike "*id=*" ) -and ($_ -Notlike "*likes=*")){$_ }}
```

I get the result as:

```
We are happy with the service
hsbdinsjsonsjbdjdjid
```

I wish to only get "we are happy with the service".

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that the item you are looking for does not contain commas, then you are simply looking at second element in a comma delimitered string.

```
$string.split(",")[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll go for the RegEx option...

```
$string ='Comments : @{id=15161772,we are happy with the service,likes=&÷€$:#,hsbdinsjsonsjbdjdjid}'
$string -replace ".*?=.*?,(.*?),likes=.*", "`$1"
```

That outputs your desired text, and should return out everything after the first equals sign, and before `,likes=`. If you want to capture it, just assign it to a variable, such as:

```
$Comment = $string -replace ".*?=.*?,(.*?),likes=.*", "`$1"
```

Then `$Comment` will contain the string `we are happy with the service`.

This should be more flexible than splitting on the comma. See examples and more details on how the RegEx works at: https://regex101.com/r/fK1oX6/1

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex split:

```
$string = 'Comments : @{id=15161772,we are happy with the service,likes=&÷€$:#,hsbdinsjsonsjbdjdjid}'
($string -split 'id=\d+,|,likes=')[1]
we are happy with the service
```